# Python TweetStream Access Denied

Tags: python, twitter, access-denied, tweetstream

I keep getting this exception from TweetStream 1.1.1, "exception.code == 404:uthenticationError("Access denied")"  It worked last week and now it doesn't. I have tried different usernames and passwords. I can log into twitter with my account information. I even deleted and reinstalled the module. what gives? Thanks for the help!

I try running this...

```
import tweetstream
stream = tweetstream.SampleStream("MY_USERNAME", "MY_PASSWORD")
for tweet in stream:
    print tweet
```

The error actually looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
for tweet in stream:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweetstream-1.1.1-py2.7.egg\tweetstream\streamclasses.py", line 165, in __iter__
self._init_conn()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweetstream-1.1.1-py2.7.egg\tweetstream\streamclasses.py", line 103, in _init_conn
raise AuthenticationError("Access denied")
AuthenticationError: Access denied
```

Answer (score 4):

Twitter released the next version of API ([1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)). And tweetstream doesn't support it yet.  See [relevant issue](https://bitbucket.org/runeh/tweetstream/issue/26/upgrading-to-streaming-api-version-11) on tweetstream project issue tracker.

Comment: Is it still possible to use username/password authentication against Twitter.  Is it not all OAuth now, hence the Access denied?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here, and I could not get the patched version mentioned on the project issue tracker (linked by @alecxe) to work either.

Twitter provides a list of libraries that should work with the newer API, at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

It lists many, including several for Python.